# Replace Volumetric Clouds With Mesh?

Tags: unreal-4, clouds

I'm looking to replace the Volumetric Cloud shader, or at least edit it in some way, to replace the clouds with a mesh. I'd like the meshes to be duplicated (without duplicating into one another,) and randomly rotated. If anyone knows how I can possibly create this effect, please let me know. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into Marching Cubes? You can run it as a geometry shader. It converts a scalar field (fog density) into a mesh by generating an isosurface.

I have a C++ CPU implementation of Marching Cubes here: https://github.com/sjhalayka/marching_cubes

If you need GPU code, here is the sample geometry shader, in OpenGL 4 anyway:

```
#version 430 core

layout (points) in;
layout (triangle_strip) out;
layout (max_vertices = 15) out;


in VS_OUT
{
    vec4 position0;
    vec4 position1;
    vec4 position2;
    vec4 position3;
    vec4 position4;
    vec4 position5;
    vec4 position6;
    vec4 position7;
    float threshold;
} gs_in[];



struct grid_cube
{
    vec4 vertex_val[8];
};


    const int MC_EdgeTable[256]={
    0x0  , 0x109, 0x203, 0x30a, 0x406, 0x50f, 0x605, 0x70c,
    0x80c, 0x905, 0xa0f, 0xb06, 0xc0a, 0xd03, 0xe09, 0xf00,
    0x190, 0x99 , 0x393, 0x29a, 0x596, 0x49f, 0x795, 0x69c,
    0x99c, 0x895, 0xb9f, 0xa96, 0xd9a, 0xc93, 0xf99, 0xe90,
    0x230, 0x339, 0x33 , 0x13a, 0x636, 0x73f, 0x435, 0x53c,
    0xa3c, 0xb35, 0x83f, 0x936, 0xe3a, 0xf33, 0xc39, 0xd30,
    0x3a0, 0x2a9, 0x1a3, 0xaa , 0x7a6, 0x6af, 0x5a5, 0x4ac,
    0xbac, 0xaa5, 0x9af, 0x8a6, 0xfaa, 0xea3, 0xda9, 0xca0,
    0x460, 0x569, 0x663, 0x76a, 0x66 , 0x16f, 0x265, 0x36c,
    0xc6c, 0xd65, 0xe6f, 0xf66, 0x86a, 0x963, 0xa69, 0xb60,
    0x5f0, 0x4f9, 0x7f3, 0x6fa, 0x1f6, 0xff , 0x3f5, 0x2fc,
    0xdfc, 0xcf5, 0xfff, 0xef6, 0x9fa, 0x8f3, 0xbf9, 0xaf0,
    0x650, 0x759, 0x453, 0x55a, 0x256, 0x35f, 0x55 , 0x15c,
    0xe5c, 0xf55, 0xc5f, 0xd56, 0xa5a, 0xb53, 0x859, 0x950,
    0x7c0, 0x6c9, 0x5c3, 0x4ca, 0x3c6, 0x2cf, 0x1c5, 0xcc ,
    0xfcc, 0xec5, 0xdcf, 0xcc6, 0xbca, 0xac3, 0x9c9, 0x8c0, // mirrors here...
    0x8c0, 0x9c9, 0xac3, 0xbca, 0xcc6, 0xdcf, 0xec5, 0xfcc,
    0xcc , 0x1c5, 0x2cf, 0x3c6, 0x4ca, 0x5c3, 0x6c9, 0x7c0,
    0x950, 0x859, 0xb53, 0xa5a, 0xd56, 0xc5f, 0xf55, 0xe5c,
    0x15c, 0x55 , 0x35f, 0x256, 0x55a, 0x453, 0x759, 0x650,
    0xaf0, 0xbf9, 0x8f3, 0x9fa, 0xef6, 0xfff, 0xcf5, 0xdfc,
    0x2fc, 0x3f5, 0xff , 0x1f6, 0x6fa, 0x7f3, 0x4f9, 0x5f0,
    0xb60, 0xa69, 0x963, 0x86a, 0xf66, 0xe6f, 0xd65, 0xc6c,
    0x36c, 0x265, 0x16f, 0x66 , 0x76a, 0x663, 0x569, 0x460,
    0xca0, 0xda9, 0xea3, 0xfaa, 0x8a6, 0x9af, 0xaa5, 0xbac,
    0x4ac, 0x5a5, 0x6af, 0x7a6, 0xaa , 0x1a3, 0x2a9, 0x3a0,
    0xd30, 0xc39, 0xf33, 0xe3a, 0x936, 0x83f, 0xb35, 0xa3c,
    0x53c, 0x435, 0x73f, 0x636, 0x13a, 0x33 , 0x339, 0x230,
    0xe90, 0xf99, 0xc93, 0xd9a, 0xa96, 0xb9f, 0x895, 0x99c,
    0x69c, 0x795, 0x49f, 0x596, 0x29a, 0x393, 0x99 , 0x190,
    0xf00, 0xe09, 0xd03, 0xc0a, 0xb06, 0xa0f, 0x905, 0x80c,
    0x70c, 0x605, 0x50f, 0x406, 0x30a, 0x203, 0x109, 0x0   };

 const int MC_TriTable[256][16] =
    {{-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {0, 8, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {0, 1, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {1, 8, 3, 9, 8, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {1, 2, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {0, 8, 3, 1, 2, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {9, 2, 10, 0, 2, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {2, 8, 3, 2, 10, 8, 10, 9, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {3, 11, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {0, 11, 2, 8, 11, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {1, 9, 0, 2, 3, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {1, 11, 2, 1, 9, 11, 9, 8, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {3, 10, 1, 11, 10, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {0, 10, 1, 0, 8, 10, 8, 11, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {3, 9, 0, 3, 11, 9, 11, 10, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {9, 8, 10, 10, 8, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {4, 7, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {4, 3, 0, 7, 3, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {0, 1, 9, 8, 4, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {4, 1, 9, 4, 7, 1, 7, 3, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {1, 2, 10, 8, 4, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {3, 4, 7, 3, 0, 4, 1, 2, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {9, 2, 10, 9, 0, 2, 8, 4, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {2, 10, 9, 2, 9, 7, 2, 7, 3, 7, 9, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {8, 4, 7, 3, 11, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {11, 4, 7, 11, 2, 4, 2, 0, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {9, 0, 1, 8, 4, 7, 2, 3, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {4, 7, 11, 9, 4, 11, 9, 11, 2, 9, 2, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {3, 10, 1, 3, 11, 10, 7, 8, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {1, 11, 10, 1, 4, 11, 1, 0, 4, 7, 11, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 11, 9, 11, 10, 11, 0, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {4, 7, 11, 4, 11, 9, 9, 11, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {9, 5, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {9, 5, 4, 0, 8, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {0, 5, 4, 1, 5, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {8, 5, 4, 8, 3, 5, 3, 1, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {1, 2, 10, 9, 5, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {3, 0, 8, 1, 2, 10, 4, 9, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {5, 2, 10, 5, 4, 2, 4, 0, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {2, 10, 5, 3, 2, 5, 3, 5, 4, 3, 4, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {9, 5, 4, 2, 3, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {0, 11, 2, 0, 8, 11, 4, 9, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {0, 5, 4, 0, 1, 5, 2, 3, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {2, 1, 5, 2, 5, 8, 2, 8, 11, 4, 8, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {10, 3, 11, 10, 1, 3, 9, 5, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {4, 9, 5, 0, 8, 1, 8, 10, 1, 8, 11, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {5, 4, 0, 5, 0, 11, 5, 11, 10, 11, 0, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {5, 4, 8, 5, 8, 10, 10, 8, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {9, 7, 8, 5, 7, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {9, 3, 0, 9, 5, 3, 5, 7, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {0, 7, 8, 0, 1, 7, 1, 5, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {1, 5, 3, 3, 5, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {9, 7, 8, 9, 5, 7, 10, 1, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {10, 1, 2, 9, 5, 0, 5, 3, 0, 5, 7, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {8, 0, 2, 8, 2, 5, 8, 5, 7, 10, 5, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {2, 10, 5, 2, 5, 3, 3, 5, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {7, 9, 5, 7, 8, 9, 3, 11, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {9, 5, 7, 9, 7, 2, 9, 2, 0, 2, 7, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {2, 3, 11, 0, 1, 8, 1, 7, 8, 1, 5, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {11, 2, 1, 11, 1, 7, 7, 1, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {9, 5, 8, 8, 5, 7, 10, 1, 3, 10, 3, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {5, 7, 0, 5, 0, 9, 7, 11, 0, 1, 0, 10, 11, 10, 0, -1},
    {11, 10, 0, 11, 0, 3, 10, 5, 0, 8, 0, 7, 5, 7, 0, -1},
    {11, 10, 5, 7, 11, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {10, 6, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {0, 8, 3, 5, 10, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {9, 0, 1, 5, 10, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {1, 8, 3, 1, 9, 8, 5, 10, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {1, 6, 5, 2, 6, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {1, 6, 5, 1, 2, 6, 3, 0, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {9, 6, 5, 9, 0, 6, 0, 2, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {5, 9, 8, 5, 8, 2, 5, 2, 6, 3, 2, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {2, 3, 11, 10, 6, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {11, 0, 8, 11, 2, 0, 10, 6, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {0, 1, 9, 2, 3, 11, 5, 10, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {5, 10, 6, 1, 9, 2, 9, 11, 2, 9, 8, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {6, 3, 11, 6, 5, 3, 5, 1, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {0, 8, 11, 0, 11, 5, 0, 5, 1, 5, 11, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {3, 11, 6, 0, 3, 6, 0, 6, 5, 0, 5, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {6, 5, 9, 6, 9, 11, 11, 9, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {5, 10, 6, 4, 7, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {4, 3, 0, 4, 7, 3, 6, 5, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {1, 9, 0, 5, 10, 6, 8, 4, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {10, 6, 5, 1, 9, 7, 1, 7, 3, 7, 9, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {6, 1, 2, 6, 5, 1, 4, 7, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {1, 2, 5, 5, 2, 6, 3, 0, 4, 3, 4, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {8, 4, 7, 9, 0, 5, 0, 6, 5, 0, 2, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {7, 3, 9, 7, 9, 4, 3, 2, 9, 5, 9, 6, 2, 6, 9, -1},
    {3, 11, 2, 7, 8, 4, 10, 6, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {5, 10, 6, 4, 7, 2, 4, 2, 0, 2, 7, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {0, 1, 9, 4, 7, 8, 2, 3, 11, 5, 10, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {9, 2, 1, 9, 11, 2, 9, 4, 11, 7, 11, 4, 5, 10, 6, -1},
    {8, 4, 7, 3, 11, 5, 3, 5, 1, 5, 11, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {5, 1, 11, 5, 11, 6, 1, 0, 11, 7, 11, 4, 0, 4, 11, -1},
    {0, 5, 9, 0, 6, 5, 0, 3, 6, 11, 6, 3, 8, 4, 7, -1},
    {6, 5, 9, 6, 9, 11, 4, 7, 9, 7, 11, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {10, 4, 9, 6, 4, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {4, 10, 6, 4, 9, 10, 0, 8, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {10, 0, 1, 10, 6, 0, 6, 4, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {8, 3, 1, 8, 1, 6, 8, 6, 4, 6, 1, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {1, 4, 9, 1, 2, 4, 2, 6, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {3, 0, 8, 1, 2, 9, 2, 4, 9, 2, 6, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {0, 2, 4, 4, 2, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {8, 3, 2, 8, 2, 4, 4, 2, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {10, 4, 9, 10, 6, 4, 11, 2, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {0, 8, 2, 2, 8, 11, 4, 9, 10, 4, 10, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {3, 11, 2, 0, 1, 6, 0, 6, 4, 6, 1, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {6, 4, 1, 6, 1, 10, 4, 8, 1, 2, 1, 11, 8, 11, 1, -1},
    {9, 6, 4, 9, 3, 6, 9, 1, 3, 11, 6, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {8, 11, 1, 8, 1, 0, 11, 6, 1, 9, 1, 4, 6, 4, 1, -1},
    {3, 11, 6, 3, 6, 0, 0, 6, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {6, 4, 8, 11, 6, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {7, 10, 6, 7, 8, 10, 8, 9, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {0, 7, 3, 0, 10, 7, 0, 9, 10, 6, 7, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {10, 6, 7, 1, 10, 7, 1, 7, 8, 1, 8, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {10, 6, 7, 10, 7, 1, 1, 7, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {1, 2, 6, 1, 6, 8, 1, 8, 9, 8, 6, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {2, 6, 9, 2, 9, 1, 6, 7, 9, 0, 9, 3, 7, 3, 9, -1},
    {7, 8, 0, 7, 0, 6, 6, 0, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {7, 3, 2, 6, 7, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {2, 3, 11, 10, 6, 8, 10, 8, 9, 8, 6, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {2, 0, 7, 2, 7, 11, 0, 9, 7, 6, 7, 10, 9, 10, 7, -1},
    {1, 8, 0, 1, 7, 8, 1, 10, 7, 6, 7, 10, 2, 3, 11, -1},
    {11, 2, 1, 11, 1, 7, 10, 6, 1, 6, 7, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {8, 9, 6, 8, 6, 7, 9, 1, 6, 11, 6, 3, 1, 3, 6, -1},
    {0, 9, 1, 11, 6, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {7, 8, 0, 7, 0, 6, 3, 11, 0, 11, 6, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {7, 11, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {7, 6, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {3, 0, 8, 11, 7, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {0, 1, 9, 11, 7, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {8, 1, 9, 8, 3, 1, 11, 7, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {10, 1, 2, 6, 11, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {1, 2, 10, 3, 0, 8, 6, 11, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {2, 9, 0, 2, 10, 9, 6, 11, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {6, 11, 7, 2, 10, 3, 10, 8, 3, 10, 9, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {7, 2, 3, 6, 2, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {7, 0, 8, 7, 6, 0, 6, 2, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {2, 7, 6, 2, 3, 7, 0, 1, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {1, 6, 2, 1, 8, 6, 1, 9, 8, 8, 7, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {10, 7, 6, 10, 1, 7, 1, 3, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {10, 7, 6, 1, 7, 10, 1, 8, 7, 1, 0, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {0, 3, 7, 0, 7, 10, 0, 10, 9, 6, 10, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {7, 6, 10, 7, 10, 8, 8, 10, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {6, 8, 4, 11, 8, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {3, 6, 11, 3, 0, 6, 0, 4, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {8, 6, 11, 8, 4, 6, 9, 0, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {9, 4, 6, 9, 6, 3, 9, 3, 1, 11, 3, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {6, 8, 4, 6, 11, 8, 2, 10, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {1, 2, 10, 3, 0, 11, 0, 6, 11, 0, 4, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {4, 11, 8, 4, 6, 11, 0, 2, 9, 2, 10, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {10, 9, 3, 10, 3, 2, 9, 4, 3, 11, 3, 6, 4, 6, 3, -1},
    {8, 2, 3, 8, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {0, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {1, 9, 0, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6, 4, 3, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {1, 9, 4, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {8, 1, 3, 8, 6, 1, 8, 4, 6, 6, 10, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {10, 1, 0, 10, 0, 6, 6, 0, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {4, 6, 3, 4, 3, 8, 6, 10, 3, 0, 3, 9, 10, 9, 3, -1},
    {10, 9, 4, 6, 10, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {4, 9, 5, 7, 6, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {0, 8, 3, 4, 9, 5, 11, 7, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {5, 0, 1, 5, 4, 0, 7, 6, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {11, 7, 6, 8, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 1, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {9, 5, 4, 10, 1, 2, 7, 6, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {6, 11, 7, 1, 2, 10, 0, 8, 3, 4, 9, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {7, 6, 11, 5, 4, 10, 4, 2, 10, 4, 0, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {3, 4, 8, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 5, 10, 5, 2, 11, 7, 6, -1},
    {7, 2, 3, 7, 6, 2, 5, 4, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {9, 5, 4, 0, 8, 6, 0, 6, 2, 6, 8, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {3, 6, 2, 3, 7, 6, 1, 5, 0, 5, 4, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {6, 2, 8, 6, 8, 7, 2, 1, 8, 4, 8, 5, 1, 5, 8, -1},
    {9, 5, 4, 10, 1, 6, 1, 7, 6, 1, 3, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {1, 6, 10, 1, 7, 6, 1, 0, 7, 8, 7, 0, 9, 5, 4, -1},
    {4, 0, 10, 4, 10, 5, 0, 3, 10, 6, 10, 7, 3, 7, 10, -1},
    {7, 6, 10, 7, 10, 8, 5, 4, 10, 4, 8, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {6, 9, 5, 6, 11, 9, 11, 8, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {3, 6, 11, 0, 6, 3, 0, 5, 6, 0, 9, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {0, 11, 8, 0, 5, 11, 0, 1, 5, 5, 6, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {6, 11, 3, 6, 3, 5, 5, 3, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {1, 2, 10, 9, 5, 11, 9, 11, 8, 11, 5, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {0, 11, 3, 0, 6, 11, 0, 9, 6, 5, 6, 9, 1, 2, 10, -1},
    {11, 8, 5, 11, 5, 6, 8, 0, 5, 10, 5, 2, 0, 2, 5, -1},
    {6, 11, 3, 6, 3, 5, 2, 10, 3, 10, 5, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {5, 8, 9, 5, 2, 8, 5, 6, 2, 3, 8, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {9, 5, 6, 9, 6, 0, 0, 6, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {1, 5, 8, 1, 8, 0, 5, 6, 8, 3, 8, 2, 6, 2, 8, -1},
    {1, 5, 6, 2, 1, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {1, 3, 6, 1, 6, 10, 3, 8, 6, 5, 6, 9, 8, 9, 6, -1},
    {10, 1, 0, 10, 0, 6, 9, 5, 0, 5, 6, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {0, 3, 8, 5, 6, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {10, 5, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {11, 5, 10, 7, 5, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {11, 5, 10, 11, 7, 5, 8, 3, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {5, 11, 7, 5, 10, 11, 1, 9, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {10, 7, 5, 10, 11, 7, 9, 8, 1, 8, 3, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {11, 1, 2, 11, 7, 1, 7, 5, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {0, 8, 3, 1, 2, 7, 1, 7, 5, 7, 2, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {9, 7, 5, 9, 2, 7, 9, 0, 2, 2, 11, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {7, 5, 2, 7, 2, 11, 5, 9, 2, 3, 2, 8, 9, 8, 2, -1},
    {2, 5, 10, 2, 3, 5, 3, 7, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {8, 2, 0, 8, 5, 2, 8, 7, 5, 10, 2, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {9, 0, 1, 5, 10, 3, 5, 3, 7, 3, 10, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {9, 8, 2, 9, 2, 1, 8, 7, 2, 10, 2, 5, 7, 5, 2, -1},
    {1, 3, 5, 3, 7, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {0, 8, 7, 0, 7, 1, 1, 7, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {9, 0, 3, 9, 3, 5, 5, 3, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {9, 8, 7, 5, 9, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {5, 8, 4, 5, 10, 8, 10, 11, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {5, 0, 4, 5, 11, 0, 5, 10, 11, 11, 3, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {0, 1, 9, 8, 4, 10, 8, 10, 11, 10, 4, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {10, 11, 4, 10, 4, 5, 11, 3, 4, 9, 4, 1, 3, 1, 4, -1},
    {2, 5, 1, 2, 8, 5, 2, 11, 8, 4, 5, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {0, 4, 11, 0, 11, 3, 4, 5, 11, 2, 11, 1, 5, 1, 11, -1},
    {0, 2, 5, 0, 5, 9, 2, 11, 5, 4, 5, 8, 11, 8, 5, -1},
    {9, 4, 5, 2, 11, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {2, 5, 10, 3, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 8, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {5, 10, 2, 5, 2, 4, 4, 2, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {3, 10, 2, 3, 5, 10, 3, 8, 5, 4, 5, 8, 0, 1, 9, -1},
    {5, 10, 2, 5, 2, 4, 1, 9, 2, 9, 4, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {8, 4, 5, 8, 5, 3, 3, 5, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {0, 4, 5, 1, 0, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {8, 4, 5, 8, 5, 3, 9, 0, 5, 0, 3, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {9, 4, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {4, 11, 7, 4, 9, 11, 9, 10, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {0, 8, 3, 4, 9, 7, 9, 11, 7, 9, 10, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {1, 10, 11, 1, 11, 4, 1, 4, 0, 7, 4, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {3, 1, 4, 3, 4, 8, 1, 10, 4, 7, 4, 11, 10, 11, 4, -1},
    {4, 11, 7, 9, 11, 4, 9, 2, 11, 9, 1, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {9, 7, 4, 9, 11, 7, 9, 1, 11, 2, 11, 1, 0, 8, 3, -1},
    {11, 7, 4, 11, 4, 2, 2, 4, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {11, 7, 4, 11, 4, 2, 8, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {2, 9, 10, 2, 7, 9, 2, 3, 7, 7, 4, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {9, 10, 7, 9, 7, 4, 10, 2, 7, 8, 7, 0, 2, 0, 7, -1},
    {3, 7, 10, 3, 10, 2, 7, 4, 10, 1, 10, 0, 4, 0, 10, -1},
    {1, 10, 2, 8, 7, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {4, 9, 1, 4, 1, 7, 7, 1, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {4, 9, 1, 4, 1, 7, 0, 8, 1, 8, 7, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {4, 0, 3, 7, 4, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {4, 8, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {9, 10, 8, 10, 11, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {3, 0, 9, 3, 9, 11, 11, 9, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {0, 1, 10, 0, 10, 8, 8, 10, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {3, 1, 10, 11, 3, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {1, 2, 11, 1, 11, 9, 9, 11, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {3, 0, 9, 3, 9, 11, 1, 2, 9, 2, 11, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {0, 2, 11, 8, 0, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {3, 2, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {2, 3, 8, 2, 8, 10, 10, 8, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {9, 10, 2, 0, 9, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {2, 3, 8, 2, 8, 10, 0, 1, 8, 1, 10, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {1, 10, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {1, 3, 8, 9, 1, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {0, 9, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {0, 3, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}};



int lessthan(vec4 left, vec4 right)
{
    if(left.x < right.x)
        return 1;
    else if(left.x > right.x)
        return 0;

    if(left.y < right.y)
        return 1;
    else if(left.y > right.y)
        return 0;

    if(left.z < right.z)
        return 1;
    else if(left.z > right.z)
        return 0;

    return 0;
}

vec4 vertex_interp(vec4 v0, vec4 v1)
{
    if(0 == lessthan(v0, v1))
    {
        vec4 temp = v0;
        v0 = v1;
        v1 = temp;
    }

    const float epsilon = 1e-10f;

    if(abs(gs_in[0].threshold - v0.w) < epsilon)
        return(v0);

    if(abs(gs_in[0].threshold - v1.w) < epsilon)
        return(v1);

    if(abs(v0.w - v1.w) < epsilon)
        return(v0);

    float mu = (gs_in[0].threshold - v0.w) / (v1.w - v0.w);

    return v0 + (v1 - v0)*mu;
}

int tesselate_grid_cube(grid_cube grid)
{
    int cubeindex = 0;

    if(grid.vertex_val[0].w < gs_in[0].threshold) cubeindex |= 1;
    if(grid.vertex_val[1].w < gs_in[0].threshold) cubeindex |= 2;
    if(grid.vertex_val[2].w < gs_in[0].threshold) cubeindex |= 4;
    if(grid.vertex_val[3].w < gs_in[0].threshold) cubeindex |= 8;
    if(grid.vertex_val[4].w < gs_in[0].threshold) cubeindex |= 16;
    if(grid.vertex_val[5].w < gs_in[0].threshold) cubeindex |= 32;
    if(grid.vertex_val[6].w < gs_in[0].threshold) cubeindex |= 64;
    if(grid.vertex_val[7].w < gs_in[0].threshold) cubeindex |= 128;

    if(0 == MC_EdgeTable[cubeindex])
        return 0;

    vec4 vertlist[12];

    if(MC_EdgeTable[cubeindex] & 1)
        vertlist[0] = vertex_interp(grid.vertex_val[0], grid.vertex_val[1]);

    if(MC_EdgeTable[cubeindex] & 2)
        vertlist[1] = vertex_interp(grid.vertex_val[1], grid.vertex_val[2]);

    if(MC_EdgeTable[cubeindex] & 4)
        vertlist[2] = vertex_interp(grid.vertex_val[2], grid.vertex_val[3]);

    if(MC_EdgeTable[cubeindex] & 8)
        vertlist[3] = vertex_interp(grid.vertex_val[3], grid.vertex_val[0]);

    if(MC_EdgeTable[cubeindex] & 16)
        vertlist[4] = vertex_interp(grid.vertex_val[4], grid.vertex_val[5]);

    if(MC_EdgeTable[cubeindex] & 32)
        vertlist[5] = vertex_interp(grid.vertex_val[5], grid.vertex_val[6]);

    if(MC_EdgeTable[cubeindex] & 64)
        vertlist[6] = vertex_interp(grid.vertex_val[6], grid.vertex_val[7]);

    if(MC_EdgeTable[cubeindex] & 128)
        vertlist[7] = vertex_interp(grid.vertex_val[7], grid.vertex_val[4]);

    if(MC_EdgeTable[cubeindex] & 256)
        vertlist[8] = vertex_interp(grid.vertex_val[0], grid.vertex_val[4]);

    if(MC_EdgeTable[cubeindex] & 512)
        vertlist[9] = vertex_interp(grid.vertex_val[1], grid.vertex_val[5]);

    if(MC_EdgeTable[cubeindex] & 1024)
        vertlist[10] = vertex_interp(grid.vertex_val[2], grid.vertex_val[6]);

    if(MC_EdgeTable[cubeindex] & 2048)
        vertlist[11] = vertex_interp(grid.vertex_val[3], grid.vertex_val[7]);

    int ntriang = 0; // Max triangles == 5

    for(int i = 0; MC_TriTable[cubeindex][i] != -1; i += 3)
    {
        vec4 vertex0, vertex1, vertex2;

        vertex0.x = vertlist[MC_TriTable[cubeindex][i]].x;
        vertex0.y = vertlist[MC_TriTable[cubeindex][i]].y;
        vertex0.z = vertlist[MC_TriTable[cubeindex][i]].z;
        vertex0.w = 0;

        vertex1.x = vertlist[MC_TriTable[cubeindex][i + 1]].x;
        vertex1.y = vertlist[MC_TriTable[cubeindex][i + 1]].y;
        vertex1.z = vertlist[MC_TriTable[cubeindex][i + 1]].z;
        vertex1.w = 0;

        vertex2.x = vertlist[MC_TriTable[cubeindex][i + 2]].x;
        vertex2.y = vertlist[MC_TriTable[cubeindex][i + 2]].y;
        vertex2.z = vertlist[MC_TriTable[cubeindex][i + 2]].z;
        vertex2.w = 0;

        gl_Position = vertex0;
        EmitVertex();
        gl_Position = vertex1;
        EmitVertex();
        gl_Position = vertex2;
        EmitVertex();

        EndPrimitive();

        ntriang++;
    }

    return ntriang;
}

void main(void)
{
    grid_cube g;
    g.vertex_val[0] = gs_in[0].position0;
    g.vertex_val[1] = gs_in[0].position1;
    g.vertex_val[2] = gs_in[0].position2;
    g.vertex_val[3] = gs_in[0].position3;
    g.vertex_val[4] = gs_in[0].position4;
    g.vertex_val[5] = gs_in[0].position5;
    g.vertex_val[6] = gs_in[0].position6;
    g.vertex_val[7] = gs_in[0].position7;

    int n = tesselate_grid_cube(g);
}
```